# Passing a variable to PHP with jQuery and $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery php script which accesses a database and echoes back html to fill a div on my page. It uses the following code.

```
function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function (msg) {
        $("#divholder").html(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
}
```

What I need to do is also send a variable through to the script so it knows what to look for in the database. I have been searching but I can't seem to find quite the right answer. Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Check the manual on `$.ajax`, you are looking for the `data` key: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: even if @jeroen 's comment is the correct way, you can simply edit the url of your ajax (example: `ajax.php?var1=value&var2=othervalue`) but it's not really the best way.

Comment: RTFM: read the fine manual. No effort.

Comment: Cheers Tim, you're a funny guy. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @senortee I was explaining my downvote, which is something one should do on this website. Something else that one should do on this website is to do a modicum of research before posting and to show effort. Have you read the FAQ?

Comment: I apologise for my sarcastic reply, I read your RTFM as the more commonly used F word, I thought you were being rude. I am not a programmer by trade and researched for an hour before coming here to find an answer that more specifically solved my issue. I am well aware of the rules. Thanks for taking the time to respond though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the parameter like this :

```
function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?param1=" + 'parameter',
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#divholder").html(msg);          
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

And get the parameter with $_GET

Or you can send the parameter with POST (look at data : [Ajax jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, am guessing you give it to the first responder. Just wanted to say cheers.

Comment: @senortee In the interest of fairness, this was the first answer posted whilst I was writing mine.

Comment: Thanks for that David, I misunderstood the flow of the page. Amended!

Comment: @senortee You can decide to give it to whichever answer you find best, btw. There is no rule, only your preference.

Answer (score 1):

With a get request just append it to the url.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'ajax.php?someVar=20',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'html'
)}
```

You can also add it to the data property and jQuery will url encode your data and append it to the url string.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'ajax.php',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'html',
    data : {
        someVar : 20
    }
)}
```